# error when trying to do a running sum in r with sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

I am trying to calculate a running sum in R using sqldf.

I have tried several ways, and I keep getting an this error,

error in statement: near "(": syntax error

I have a pretty simple example dataframe
`DF <- data.frame(col1 = 1:4, id = 1:12)`

[image]

And this is what I am trying to do

```
install.packages('sqldf')
require(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT col1, SUM(col1) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS runningsum FROM DF")
```

I want to get something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) sqlite** with the default sqlite backend to sqldf that syntax is not supported but this works:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, sum(b.col1) as runningSum
  from DF as a
  left join DF b on a.id >= b.id
  group by a.id")
```

giving:

```
   col1 id runningSum
1     1  1          1
2     2  2          3
3     3  3          6
4     4  4         10
5     1  5         11
6     2  6         13
7     3  7         16
8     4  8         20
9     1  9         21
10    2 10         23
11    3 11         26
12    4 12         30
```

**2) H2**  With the H2 backend we can do this:

```
library(RH2)
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select *, set(@i, ifnull(@i, 0) + col1) as runningSum from DF")
```

**3) PostgreSQL**  With the PostgreSQL back end it could be done like this:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(sqldf)

sqldf('select
  *,
  sum(col1) over (order by id asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from "DF"')
```